# Upvotes on bad questions

Tags: discussion

I'm just curious where upvotes on (new) bad questions come from, like i.e. this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51207159/4746087). Is it some sort of serial upvoting? Or are these upvoters also kind of new and do they need some guide on upvoting too? Like a guide on how to ask questions?

Comment: We can't actually tell, even less than what makes a warranted downvote.

Comment: Because Tim **found** his keys!!! :)

Comment: You may be curious about the up-votes, but you didn't down-vote or close-vote that question either.

Comment: @yivi, indeed not yet, but that's only to show a temporarily light on the upvotes. Will do later today.

Comment: Well, this user has only three non-deleted questions, [all of questionable quailty, and all of them positively scored](https://imgur.com/a/DcdoMy1)... I wonder if it's worth a custom flag.

Comment: A bad question is always worth a flag or downvote. And looking into his/her other questions in depth, the same upvoting behaviour seems to take place, but that's a subjective point of view from my side.